# How can I perform operation in SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Im making a command that will compute for fine if the books overdue. this is my code

```
if (duedate.Value < DateTime.Now)
{
    cmd.CommandText = ("UPDATE Penalty SET Penalty = '"+ (dateTimePicker1.Text - duedate.Value)*50 +"' WHERE Title = '" + textBox3.Text + "'");
    ...
}
```

This code is not running because it has an error on `(dateTimePicker1.Text - duedate.Value)`

Comment: What is type of `duedate.Value`? and `dateTimePicker1.Text` is `string` you cant perform subtraction in `string`

Comment: That code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. This is **really bad!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you try to subtract datetime from string, try below

```
(dateTimePicker1.Value- duedate.Value).TotalDays*50
```

Answer (score 2):

Elegant way to compose query is parametrized queries: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx

In pseudocode:

```
d1 = compute the Penalty value
```

Then, make your command

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Penalty SET Penalty = @d1 WHERE Title = @d2";
cmd.Parameters.Add ("@d1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = d1;
```

Comment: Will this compile? `(dateTimePicker1.Text - duedate.Value)`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, obviously, no, don't compile. I forgot to say that this is pseudocode. I will fix it.

Comment: You addressed other issues. But failed to point the main issue that is why OP is here. Now your answer looks fine +1

Answer (score 0):

Ick! Egads! Holy type mismatch Batman!

- Parameratize your SQL queries, else be the fodder of [SQL Injection attacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163917.aspx)!
- Don't try to subtract a date from a string.  That's nonsensical.
- Don't do math with `DateTime.Now`.  [Read why here](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).
- Don't hardcode the `50`.  I assume that's the dollar amount per day of the fine.

  - That should be passed in a variable so you can adjust it later if needed.
  - You need to first get to *whole days*.

Answer (score 0):

This work's, cast/convert the inner value first and then subtract then the final outer cast.

cast to datetime (cast to datetime (dateTimePicker1.Text) - cast to datetime (duedate.Value))*50